# Feign Client exception feign.codec.DecodeException: type is not an instance of Class or ParameterizedType: T

Tags: java, spring-boot, generics, spring-cloud-feign

I am trying to make my feign client generic and this is throwing me an exception when the call is finished.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

code i am trying:

```
@PostMapping("/api/{path}")
    <T> T save(@PathVariable("path") String path,
                            @RequestBody T entity)
```

Exception:

````
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringDecoder.decode(SpringDecoder.java:62)
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.ResponseEntityDecoder.decode(ResponseEntityDecoder.java:45)
    at feign.optionals.OptionalDecoder.decode(OptionalDecoder.java:23)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.decode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:165)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.executeAndDecode(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:133)
    at feign.SynchronousMethodHandler.invoke(SynchronousMethodHandler.java:76)
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$FeignInvocationHandler.invoke(ReflectiveFeign.java:103)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy208.save(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)```
````